# Cordova Mac Can't Run Emulator - Build Folder Not Appearing

Tags: macos, cordova

I have installed everything as required to run cordova simulation, here is the requirement output:

```
Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: installed darwin
Xcode: installed [object Object]
ios-deploy: installed [object Object]
CocoaPods: installed [object Object]
```

I have created the project no problem and added iOS platform but when i run:

```
cordova emulate iOS
```

i just get this error:

```
/Users/username/Documents/cordova/hello2/platforms/ios/build/emulator/HelloWorld2.app/Info.plist file not found.
```

I've tried everything, even with sudo it doesn't work and in fact the platforms/ios/build folder doesn't even get created. It also doesn't work with cordova build ios

Comment: Same issue. However, I have not updated my Mac yet... I am still using High Sierra. The only reasons I can see why this is happened is because xcode has updated itself and is looking for the emulator build files in a different place to what it used to. Ionic CLI should bring out an update soon for this.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Happened since iOS12 came out.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same problem exists here. Tried to create the folder manually, but it is removed by the command.